# Why the bar chart disappear when the last BarEntry hide?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I have a bar graph where I basically limit my screen to 12 bars, however, because the values ​​are small, I want to allow users to zoom in to see the values ​​better. What happens is the following, if my last bar of the graph is not visible, then, no bar is visible, however, if the last bar is in the frame, then the zoom works normal and the graph does not disappear.

See some examples in these images, first, the full normal chart:

[Standard Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn0l0.png)

[All Still visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwN75.png)

Now, I'm going to zoom in on my graph a little bit, notice that the labels start to disappear as the last bar is out of view:

[Labels auto hide on zoom in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFYWE.png)

At that moment, if I zoom in to the point that the last bar leaves the view, the whole graph disappears from the view, no bar is displayed for me, it will only be displayed again if my last bar returns to view:

[All bar hide now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cXHc.png)

My important code quotes:

```
XAxis xAxis = barsWeight.getXAxis(); // barsWeight is BarChart 
                xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP);
                xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
                xAxis.setGranularity(0f);
                xAxis.setLabelCount(11);
                xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);

ArrayList<String> monthList= new ArrayList<>();
                monthList.add("JAN");
                monthList.add("FEV");
                monthList.add("MAR");
                monthList.add("ABR");
                monthList.add("MAI");
                monthList.add("JUN");
                monthList.add("JUL");
                monthList.add("AGO");
                monthList.add("SET");
                monthList.add("OUT");
                monthList.add("NOV");
                monthList.add("DEZ");

                xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(monthList));
```

Basically what I do in addition is to add a Bar Data to my Bar Chart, my Bar Data contains a single Bar Data Set that contains an array of BarEntry

Any suspicion as to why the visualization disappears if the last bar entry is not visible in the graph?

Add data:

```
 private void setDataBar( ArrayList<BarEntry> dadosPeso, BarChart barrasGraf, boolean isKg){
        BarDataSet barDataSet;

        if(barrasGraf.getData() != null && barrasGraf.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0){
            barDataSet = (BarDataSet) barrasGraf.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
            barDataSet.setValues(dadosPeso);
            barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);
            if(isKg){
                barrasGraf.getBarData().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter() {
                    @Override
                    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                        return df.format(value) + " Kg";
                    }
                });
            }else{
                barrasGraf.getBarData().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter() {
                    @Override
                    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                        return df.format(value) + " @";
                    }
                });
            }
            barrasGraf.getData().notifyDataChanged();
            barrasGraf.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else{
            barDataSet = new BarDataSet(dadosPeso, "Pesagens para cada data");
            barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);
            
            barDataSet.setDrawIcons(false);

            ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
            dataSets.add(barDataSet);

            BarData dadosBarra = new BarData(dataSets);
            dadosBarra.setValueTextSize(15f);

            dadosBarra.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            if(isKg) {
                dadosBarra.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter() {
                    @Override
                    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                        return df.format(value) + " Kg";
                    }
                });
            }else{
                dadosBarra.setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter() {
                    @Override
                    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                        return df.format(value) + " @";
                    }
                });
            }
            dadosBarra.setBarWidth(.9f);

            barrasGraf.setData(dadosBarra);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the whole class where you put these codes in?

Comment: The original class have more 890+ lines... i cut the part of the graph is used and important

Comment: Can you add both dadosBarra.setDragEnabled(true) and dadosBarra.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(2) ?